# AG grid columnfilter, filter one value

Tags: filter, ag-grid

I'm using agSetColumnFilter to filter an column in the datagrid. I populated with values from an API but I only want the user to be able to filter 1 value. Now its possible to filter multiple values at once in set column. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

- you want to have an "exclusive SetFilter"
- basically replacing the current checkbox selection with radiobuttons
- being able to filter only on a single value at a time

This is not possible with the built-in agSetColumnFilter.
To achieve this you need to provide a custom filter component, see this one as an example: https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-filter/#example-custom-filter